# How to add all data to my array to use with a color scale?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a force directed graph. The JSON data I am using looks like this :

```
var network = {
  network: {
    data: {
      edges: [
        {
          directed: true,
          id: "B_FRED_BEN",
          "source": "FRED",
          "target": "BEN",
          "classif": "A",
          "label": "A"
        }],
        nodes: [
        {
          "id": "FRED",
          "classif": "B",
          "createdOn": "2013-09-09",
          "label": "2",
        }]}}}
```

To link my nodes i use this :

```
nodesData = network.network.data.nodes;
    edgesData = network.network.data.edges;
edges = [];
    edgesData.forEach(function(e) { 
    var sourceNode = nodesData.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source;})[0];
    var targetNode = nodesData.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.target; })[0];

    edges.push({source: sourceNode, target: targetNode});//, value: e.Value});
    });
```

This only puts the source and target into the array. I want to colour the links in depending what data it has :

```
links.style("stroke", function(d) { clog(d.label) });
```

I cant do this as I am using the populated `edges` array as above as my data for the links and this only has the source and target data in it not the `label` data I need.

How do I go about adding the rest of this data to the edges array ?

I have tried this :

```
nodesData = network.network.data.nodes;
    edgesData = network.network.data.edges;

    edges = [];
    edgesData.forEach(function(e) { 
    var directed = e.directed,
        id = e.id,
        sourceNode = nodesData.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source;})[0],
        targetNode = nodesData.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.target; })[0],
        classif = e.classif,
        label = e.label;

    edges.push({directed: directed, id: id, source: sourceNode, target: targetNode, classif: classif, label: label});//, value: e.Value});
    });
```

This doesn't work :/

What I want is to colour the links (edges) depending what `label` it has in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is `coreId: coreId` which is creating the issue, You have not defined `coreId` anywhere. Remove it and try.